# Is there a function in google sheets that will return only the unique characters in a string?

Tags: regex, join, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula

Is there a function in google sheets that will return only the unique characters in a string?

for example if I input "RRRWWWGGRWG"

it will return "RWG"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sure, try:

```
=JOIN(, UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2, REPT("(.)", LEN(A2))))))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Mid and Sequence:

```
=ArrayFormula(join(,unique(mid(A1,sequence(len(A1)),1))))
```